# Ukit modal prevent close on escape button

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, modal-dialog, uikit

I'm using Uikit with Angularjs and i need create possibly a directive that prevent the closing of the Modal when i press esc button. I tried with this way:

```
mainApp.directive('ngEsc', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress keyup", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 27) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

And then put the directive on the modal

Test modal

But it still closes. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 6):

Below is how I fixed this issue in my angular 7 project;

`uikit.modal("#modalR", { bgClose: false, escClose: false, modal: false, keyboard:false}).show(this.data)`

for more information please visit link below
https://github.com/uikit/uikit/blob/develop/src/js/core/modal.js#L15:L21

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to use the option `keyboard:false`?

```
UIkit.modal("#modal element", {bgclose: false, keyboard:false}).show();
```

It worked in my case.

You can see the core of modal uikit as well: [modal.js](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/blob/5a9b8217830bc504312b2da7adbe582c271b1a57/src/js/core/modal.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can try use "return false" instead of preventDefault:

```
mainApp.directive('ngEsc', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress keyup", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 27) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, it's working but i need to focus the entire modal to make it working. I mean, when it opens if i press esc it doesn't work and it closes the modal. If i open the modal and i click into it and then i press esc it works and it doesn't close it.. Is there a way to solve this last problem?